# String format TimeSpan in xslt 1.0

Tags: c#, xslt

I have an Xml data that contains a TimeSpan duration. I would like to present this duration in number of minutes with Xslt transformation. I use Xslt 1.0. Someone have the answer ?

```
DATA : <RDS_TM_TIMESPAN>PT1M15.981S</RDS_TM_TIMESPAN>

XSLT : <xsl:value-of select="((n:RDS_TM_TIMESPAN) div 1000) div 60"/>
```

The result is **NaN**

Comment: In what way is `PT1M15.981S` a `TimeSpan` value? In what way does this question have anything to do with C#?

Comment: Is the duration **always** in the same format of minutes and seconds?

Comment: PT1M15.981S is the xml serialisation of TimeSpan in C#

Comment: Not quite; `PT1M15.981S` is an instance of an XML Schema **duration** datatype: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#duration

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using a script, and without manipulate the string.

```
  <ms:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[
     public string TimeSpanFormat(string p_Duration){
       return XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(p_Duration).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
     }
      ]]>
  </ms:script>
```